# When adding a Job to scheduler: Value cannot be null, Job class cannot be null?

Tags: javascript, c#, api, quartz.net

My question is very similar to:
[Quartz.net - "Job's key cannot be null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465700/quartz-net-jobs-key-cannot-be-null#)
However its different setup as I am using Rest API.
I am able to run a job when adding through Startup.cs however when I call API to add job using javascript it fails with below error:

ERROR:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'typeName')

   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName)

   at Quartz.Web.Api.JobsController.AddJob(String schedulerName, String jobGroup, String jobName, String jobType, Boolean durable, Boolean requestsRecovery, Boolean replace) in E:\Amit\DotNet\QuartzApi\QuartzApi\Controllers\JobsController.cs:line 108

   at lambda_method14(Closure , Object )

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

--- End of stack trace from previous location ---

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

 

HEADERS

=======

Accept: application/json

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

Connection: close

Content-Length: 83

Content-Type: application/json

Host: localhost:44379

Referer: https://localhost:44379/jobs.html

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36

sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"

sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0

origin: https://localhost:44379

sec-fetch-site: same-origin

sec-fetch-mode: cors

sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

**SETUP:**

In VS, I created Quartz REST API and front end in a single project. Running the project loads webpage with Jobs and API running in the background.

All controller endpoints work except AddJob. (i.e. get jobs, view job details, pause, resume, trigger, delete)

**Dependency:**
Quartz.Extensions.Hosting 3.3.3

**JobsController.cs**
[quartznet/JobsController.cs at main · quartznet/quartznet · GitHub](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/main/src/Quartz.Web/Api/JobsController.cs)

```
    [HttpPut]

    [Route("{jobGroup}/{jobName}")]

    public async Task AddJob(string schedulerName, string jobGroup, string jobName, string jobType, bool durable, bool requestsRecovery, bool replace = false)

    {

        var scheduler = await GetScheduler(schedulerName).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl(jobName, jobGroup, Type.GetType(jobType), durable, requestsRecovery);

        await scheduler.AddJob(jobDetail, replace).ConfigureAwait(false);

    }
```

**HelloWorldJob.cs:**
https://andrewlock.net/using-quartz-net-with-asp-net-core-and-worker-services/

**Startup.cs:** (Adds a job without API and runs it using trigger at start)

```
    void ConfigureHostQuartz(IServiceCollection services)

    {

        services.AddQuartz(q =>

        {

            q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory();



            var jobKey = new JobKey("HelloWorldJob");

            q.AddJob<HelloWorldJob>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey));

            q.AddTrigger(opts => opts

                .ForJob(jobKey)

                .WithIdentity("HelloWorldJob-trigger")

                .WithCronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"));

        });



        services.AddQuartzHostedService(

            q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);

    }
```

**Html/Javascript front end:**
Following this example:
[Tutorial: Call an ASP.NET Core web API with JavaScript | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" onsubmit="addJob()">

    <input type="text" id="add-name" placeholder="New job">

    <input type="submit" value="Add">

</form>

<script>

function addJob() {

    const addNameTextbox = document.getElementById('add-name').value.trim();

 

    const item = {

        jobType: "HelloWorldJob",

        durable: true,

        requestsRecovery: false,

        replace: false

    };

 

    fetch(`${uri}/DEFAULT/${addNameTextbox}`, {

        method: 'PUT',

        headers: {

            'Accept': 'application/json',

            'Content-Type': 'application/json'

        },

        body: JSON.stringify(item)

    })

        .then(response => console.log(response))

        .then(() => {

            getJobs();

            addNameTextbox.value = '';

        })

        .catch(error => console.error('Unable to add job.', error));

}

</script>
```

I have tried updating the API to include jobType in url, then it gives different error:

```
Job class cannot be null
at Qurtz.Impl.JobDetilImpl.set_JobType(Type value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**API controller changes:**

As mentioned by Marko above, jobType needs fully qualified name, assembly reference is not however necessary in my case as I have jobs in same assembly.

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("{jobGroup}/{jobName}/{jobType}/{replace}/new")]
    public async Task NewJob(string schedulerName, string jobGroup,
        string jobName, string jobType, bool replace = false)
    {
        //Note: Job added without a trigger must be durable.
        var scheduler = await GetScheduler(schedulerName).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var jobDetail = new JobDetailImpl(jobName, jobGroup, 
            Type.GetType("QuartzApi.Jobs." + jobType), true, false);
        await scheduler.AddJob(jobDetail, replace).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

**JavaScript fetch query changes:**

Removed JSON body tag and added extra parameters to url. Note its a job without trigger. At a later stage jobType can be a variable, for now its included in fetch string.

```
function addJob() {
    const addNameTextbox = document.getElementById('add-name').value.trim();

    fetch(`${uri}/DEFAULT/${addNameTextbox}/HelloWorldJob/false/new`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .then(() => {
            getJobs();
            addNameTextbox.value = '';
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Unable to add job.', error));
}
```

Running the UI request to add job, now adds it without a trigger (to be worked on in separate section). To confirm, I then ran API request in browser to fetch all jobs for the running scheduler using:
[https://localhost:44379/api/schedulers/QuartzScheduler/jobs]
resulting in:

```
[{"name":"HelloWorldJob","group":"DEFAULT"},{"name":"TestJob","group":"DEFAULT"}]
```

That implies a few things:

1. Passing JSON object in body does not associate it with API function parameters. I need to add all parameters in url string to use them. May be there is a way to use body parameters.
2. Now that the class is correctly referenced in API, I can continue passing just the class name through UI, without namespace and assembly to keep it secure as class is defined in the project at build time.
3. Adding Console.Writeline in API function did not return any output at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply assembly qualified name as job type. Problems is here:

```
jobType: "HelloWorldJob",
```

`jobType` should be something like `"MyNameSpace.JobType, MyAssembly"` - you can probably get this written to console with `Console.WriteLine(typeof(HelloWorldJob).AssemblyQualifiedName)` - you can ignore the version etc, only type name with namespace and assembly name are needed.

Please also note that your setup has security implications as you allow CLR types to be passed from the UI.

Comment: Thanks Marko for your answer. That did not work quiet well. The whole idea of API is to give JobType in UI (which is job class name) and let API figure it out, which it is supposed to do in [... JobDetailImpl(... Type.GetType(jobType) ...]
Upon further tweaking HttpPut method in API, I discovered that the JSON object that contains jobType, durable etc passed in body tag is ignored in API. Console.Writeline does not output anything. I was able to work out the cause and will elaborate in my answer soon. But your input was very helpful and intrigued me to investigate further!